# True proc from a method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there a way to get a true `proc` from a method in Ruby?

An `UnboundMethod` obtained via `instance_method` does not fit the bill because I can only bind it to an object of the class that declared the method. I can't reinterpret `self` inside the method body the way I could in  a `proc` (using `instance_exec`).

Similarly, a `Method` obtained via `method` is not okay, because `self` is bound to the receiver of `method` and I cannot change it.

Edit (Clarification):

What I'm trying to do is to take a method defined in one class and transfer it to another class. This means I need to be able to reinterpret the meaning of `self` within the method. For `proc`s, this is possible via `instance_exec` and `instance_eval`, but not for methods.

Why I am trying to move methods from one class to another? Long story short, to implement a form of namespacing, as I am most displeased with the visibility control provided by Ruby (there is no way to hide a module member to an including class). This is however far beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you follow duck typing, `Method`s and `Proc`s are interchangeable.

Comment: See clarification + my answer to megas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `to_proc` from `Method` can help you:

```
class A
  def test
    puts 'this is a test'
  end
end

m = A.new.method(:test)

m.to_proc.call #=> this is a test
```

UPDATE: Just an idea

By using [sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify) gem convert `proc` from first object to source, and then evaulate it in the context of second object

Comment: And for completeness, let us mention #source_location method.

Comment: See clarification. It doesn't work for because I cannot change the meaning of `self` inside the method body, like I could if it was a proc. See this paste to understand the issue http://pastebin.com/0pDrVEAt .

Comment: Can you change the second class a little bit? In purpose to get kind_of? to return true.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in practice in my namespace-thingy. I wondered if there was a truly general way to convert a method to a proc, because I suppose there are other cases where it could come in handy.

Comment: It wouldn't work because it's a method I want to convert. If I try to get the source code of a method converted to proc, it'll just spew a `Sourcify::CannotHandleCreatedOnTheFlyProcError`. What can be done is to get the method source, then to parse/edit the string to make it a proc and eval that. It's pretty ugly :p

Comment: So, what I want doesn't seem to be exactly possible. I'm accepting this answer for best effort + workaround elements.